# React elements not showing

Tags: reactjs, element

This has probably been asked a gazillion times before and I've looked at a hundred different places and tried a 100 different ways with more and less useEffects and returns here and there but I just can't fix it!

I'm trying to display stuff from a list of movies but cannot get it to show.
I can see in logs that I do have the stuff i need in "movies" in the second useEffect but it doesnt produce any elements, I only get the wrapping div.

My code rn:

```
const SideScroller = ({scrollerName, titles}) => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [content, setContent] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        let moviesTemp = [];
        
        titles.forEach(title => {
            async function fetchData() {
                const movie = await getMovie(title);
                moviesTemp.push(movie);
            }
            fetchData();
        });
        setMovies(moviesTemp);
    }, [titles])
   
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(movies)
        setContent(() => {
            return (
                movies.map((movie) => {
                    console.log(movie);
                    return (
                        <div className='scrollerItem'>
                            <img src={movie.Poster} alt={movie.Title}  />
                            <p>{movie.Title}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            );
        });
    }, [movies])

    return (
        <div className='sideScroller'>
            {content}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure setMovies(0 is called after the fetchData method finishes?

Comment: replace the `forEach` with the classic `for-of`, and it should work.

Comment: In the _second_ useeffect I can see from console logs that the movies list is populated so I guess that part works?

Comment: to me, the second `useEffect` has no sense at all. Once the `movies` array is populated, why not feeding it straight into the rendering stage?

Comment: Please check the `titles` data if there is ( `Poster` or `poster` ) and ( `Title` or `title` )

Comment: And if those are lowercase use `movie.poster`, `movie.title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dropping the promise from the `forEach` on the floor and not awaiting it. This is actually the same as the famous [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let moviesTemp = [];
        
        const fetch = async () => {
         await Promise.all(titles.map(title => {
            async function fetchData() {
                const movie = await getMovie(title);
                moviesTemp.push(movie);
            }
            return fetchData();
         }));
         setMovies(moviesTemp);
        }
        fetch();
    }, [titles])
```

Then I rewrote it a little bit for fun (not because it's necessarily any "better" than the otherway):

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const moviesTemp = [];
        const fetch = async (title) => moviesTemp.push(await getMovie(title))
        const fetchAll = async () => {
          await Promise.all(titles.map(fetch)); 
          setMovies(moviesTemp);
        }
        fetchAll();
    }, [titles])
```

EDIT: To address your second question (in the comments), it's because you've mutated state.

It's a very curious thing, but let me try to explain:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let moviesTemp = [];
        
        titles.forEach(title => {
            async function fetchData() {
                const movie = await getMovie(title);
                moviesTemp.push(movie);
            }
            fetchData();
        });
        setMovies(moviesTemp);
    }, [titles])
```

You immediately (because the `forEach` is synchronous regardless of the fact it is executing an async function on each iteration) have set the new state to `moviesTemp`, but then, you asynchronously modified `moviesTemp` which is the exact same as mutating state. If you mutate stuff in react, it doesn't work.

Also, you shouldn't have a second effect, this is what your full and final component should look like:

```
const SideScroller = ({scrollerName, titles}) => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAll = async () => setMovies(
          await Promise.all(titles.map(getMovie))
        );
        fetchAll();
    }, [titles])


    return (
        <div className='sideScroller'>
           {movies.map((movie) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='scrollerItem'>
                            <img src={movie.Poster} alt={movie.Title}  />
                            <p>{movie.Title}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: await without async?

Comment: This seems reasonable but to me the problem is really that in the _second_ useEffect the console logs prove I  have the list of movies but it doesnt produce any elements on screen.

Comment: @GregerSundvall - Yeah, I didn't pay attention to your second effect. I know exactly why you are observing that behavior, because you are mutating state, but not in the standard way that most people mutate state. Your shouldn't even have a second effect, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, this last version did it!

Answer (score 0):

> Try Like This

```
setContent(() => {
movies.map((movie) => {
console.log(movie);
return (
<div className='scrollerItem'>
<img src={movie.Poster} alt={movie.Title}  />
<p>{movie.Title}</p>
</div>
);
})
});
```

Comment: Still no child elements in the browser :(

Comment: replace this `moviesTemp.push(movie);` to `setMovies((prevState) => [..movies, movie]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const SideScroller = ({scrollerName, titles}) => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            let moviesTemp = [];
            for (const title of titles) {
                const movie = await getMovie(title);
                moviesTemp.push(movie);
            }
            setMovies(moviesTemp);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [titles])
   
    return (
        <div className='sideScroller'>
            {movies.map((movie) => {
                    console.log(movie);
                    return (
                        <div className='scrollerItem'>
                            <img src={movie.Poster} alt={movie.Title}  />
                            <p>{movie.Title}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Should there be some kind of null check for the first render where movies isnt filled? Or is it enough that that movies default to []? Anyway I still didnt get any child elements...

Comment: unless you set a non-array, the initial value and the subsequent `moviesTemp` are arrays, so there's no problem. I don't know how is your complete code, but here is a prototype using fake load and no images: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-water-84c1z?file=/src/App.tsx)